# How to check if any string from array of string contains in another string in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am writing a logic something like following code -

```
string myString = "ABCD";

if(myString.Contains("AB") && myString.Contains("C") && !myString.Contains("XYZ"))
{
    //Do something
}
```

I want to write above code something like this:

```
string myString = "ABCD";

if( myString .contains any string from new[] { "AB", "C" } )
{
   //Do Something
}
```

Can you please tell me, How can I achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if (new[]{ "AB", "C" }.Any(item => myString.Contains(item))) {...}`

Comment: You can use regular expression as well.

Comment: Note that `myString .contains any string from new[] { "AB", "C" }` is *not* the same as `myString contains "AB" and myString contains "C"`

Comment: @canton7 It is rather like myString contains "AB" OR myString contains "C", right?

Comment: @duDE Yes that is correct

Comment: @canton7 is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if the array has `Any` item such that `myString` `Contains` it:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// myString contains "AB" or "C"
if (new[]{ "AB", "C" }.Any(item => myString.Contains(item))) {
    ...
}
```

Put `All` it `myString` should contains *both* `"AB"` and `"C"`

```
// myString contains both "AB" and "C"
if (new[]{ "AB", "C" }.All(item => myString.Contains(item))) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.All()` because you are trying to check all strings present in an array

```
var checkElements = new string[]{ "AB", "C"};
//All element contains in myString then this will return true. It checks all elements
if(checkElements.All(x =>  myString.Contains(x)))
{
   //Your business logic
}
```

If you want to check, if **any** string from an array `checkElements`, present in `myString` then you can use `.Any()` from `System.Linq`

```
var checkElements = new string[]{ "AB", "C"};
//Any one element contains in myString then this will return true.
if(checkElements.Any(x =>  myString.Contains(x)))
{
   //Your business logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a little string extension method?

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static bool ContainsAnyOf(this string self, params string[] strings)
    {
        return strings.Any(self.Contains);
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
if (myString.ContainsAnyOf("AB", "C") && !myString.Contains("XYZ"))
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a candidate for an extension method!

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this string self, params string[] values)
    {
        for(int ix = 0; ix < values.Length; ++ix)
            if(!self.Contains(values[ix]))
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code like:

```
string myString = "ABCD";
if(myString.Contains("AB") && myString.Contains("C") && !myString.Contains("XYZ"))
{
    //Do something
}
```

Let's do all your checks using LINQ:

```
var theStr = "ABCD";
var rules = new string[]{ "AB", "C", "!XYZ"};
if(rules.All(rule => rule[0] == '!' ? !theStr.Contains(rule.Substring(1)) : theStr.Contains(rule)))
{
   //Do something
}
```

I do feel it's perhaps a mild abuse to put the "not" into the data by prefixing it with "!" though; consider making a Rule class that has a string and an Enum of RuleType that defines whether that string should be searched as "Contains" or "Not Contains".. Especially if you are ever going to want to find strings where one of the things you're looking for really is a string that starts with an "!"